# Put li elements side by side with horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, pagination

I am creating a paging effect using css here I confused. I want to set all li elements side by side with specifying parent width such that all li elements should scroll horizontally.

```
         <ul class="flow" style="width:200px">  
            <li class="selected">1</li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Pagina 2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Pagina 3">3</a></li>
            ...

            <li><a href="#" title="Pagina 15">15</a></li>
         </ul>
```

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2sLkouv2/) that I tried. In my fiddle li elements are breaking into new line. How can I make them to scroll horizontally in single line.

Comment: Look in mentioned duplicate above, there is a solution that can help you

Answer (score 5):

[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> **nowrap** -
>   Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  /*width:300px;*/ /* <  uncomment to check with fix width*/
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your second UL in Div and add following style to that div
please see this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/arj2p4wb/

```
   div{ 
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
```